# Create daily report using crosstabs

Tags: crystal-reports

I know that crosstabs are just for summaries. But is it possible to use a crosstab for daily reports given two dates? It's more like a details summary.

For example:

```
Date: 10 August 2012

Start Date: 10/8/2012 
End Date: 11/8/2012 

Date: 10 August 2012
_________| Center 1 | Center 2 | Total |
Person 1 |  1       |  2       | 3     |
Person 2 |  2       |  5       | 7     |
TOTAL    |  3       |  7       | 10    |

Date: 11 August 2012
_________| Center 1 | Center 2 | Total |
Person 1 |  5       |  2       | 7     |
Person 2 |  8       |  5       | 13    |
TOTAL    |  13      |  7       | 20    |
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  You need a lot more details in your question.

Comment: please see updated question above.

Comment: you can use summary along with formula and grouping to attain your requirement insteed of crosstab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you'd have to have each date as a row in the crosstab, and I think this is the best you'll be able to get:

```
10 August 2012|_________| Center 1 | Center 2 | Total |
              |Person 1 |  1       |  2       | 3     |
              |Person 2 |  2       |  5       | 7     |
              |TOTAL    |  3       |  7       | 10    |

11 August 2012|_________| Center 1 | Center 2 | Total |
              |Person 1 |  5       |  2       | 7     |
              |Person 2 |  8       |  5       | 13    |
              |TOTAL    |  13      |  7       | 20    |

              |GRAND    |  16      |  14      | 30    |
              |TOTAL    |          |          |       |
```

So your setup would be:

```
              Center  Total
----+--------+-------+------+
Date|        |       |      |
    |Person  |       |      |
```

Comment: Thanks!!! But I have one last question: Can I put the center IDs above the center name?

Comment: If you want the Center ID and the Center Name in the same cell, you can create a formula that contains the Center ID and the Name, and then use that as your column in your crosstab.